# bcp Login failed using ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, bcp

Followed the description mentioned in below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#G

Goal - Using BCP utility, trying to login to SQL server using Azure Active Directory Username and Password.

Used below command :

bcp tableName out "C:\temp\tabledata.txt" -c -t -S xxxxxxx.database.windows.net -d AzureDB -G -U xxxxxx@xxxxx.com -P xxxxx

Getting below error:

SQLState = FA004, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user 'xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryPassword').
Error code 0x800401F0; state 10
CoInitialize has not been called.

Any help ?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you don't set your public ip address and active directory to access your azure sql server. And please make sure your username and password is correct.

If you don't configure, you will face this error:

[image]

Steps how to configure:

1. allow your public ip address:

[image]

2.allow you to use AAD authentication.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have both of the steps configured as you describe in the screen capture in your reply. Do I need to create contained database users in your database mapped to Azure AD identities also ? Or any other configuration ?

Comment: @Krrish It should work. After these steps you can connect to the database.

Comment: I am able to connect to Azure DB using AD user credentials using c# and SSMS. Have bcp 15.0.1000.34 and Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server 17.4.2.1 installed in my machine. Only bcp is not working using same properties.

Comment: @Krrish After these steps the error disappear, but the terminal tell me I need to install msodbc driver 13.1 or higher. But I have already install msodbc driver 17. Do you meet the same problem? I am also have no problem when using  ssms.

Comment: @Krrish Theoretically, after the above two steps, the errors in the question you gave should not appear again.

Comment: I am able to use Azure Active Directory Interactive options. but Azure Active Directory Username and Password and Azure Active Directory Integrated does not work.